# Fixed length sequence repeats with increments in python

Tags: python

Looking for a pythonic way to repeat sequences of fixed length while incrementing the sequence digits until max length is reached.

As of now, the code uses while loop and four variables one being the list itself to complete the logic as below,

```
l = []
i, repeat, max_len = 0, 3, 20
while True:
    if len(l) + repeat <= max_len:
        l.extend([i] * repeat)
    else:
        repeat = max_len - len(l)
        l.extend([i] * repeat)
        break
    i += 1
```

The above code produces

`l = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6]`

Thus, repeating a fixed length sequence of 3 units until the maximum length of 20 is reached (omit any last digits of sequence outside max_len permitted)

Is there a pythonic way of doing the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this one:

```
[int(i/repeat) for i in range(max_len)]
```

Comment: This doesn't cover the case where `i != 0`

Answer (score 0):

Well this will make exactly your list using list comprehension.

```
l = [i//(repeat) for i in range(max_len)]
# [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6]
```

But I think there is a bug in the original function because there should be three `5`s at the end.

```
l = [i//(repeat) for i in range(max_len//repeat * repeat)]
# [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

Comment: `there is a bug in the original function`, nope actually the max_len should be reached

Answer (score 0):

With list comprehensions

```
>>> i, repeat, max_len = 0, 3, 20
>>> q = max_len//repeat
>>> [x for x in range(i, i+q) for y in range(repeat)]+[i+q for y in range(max_len%repeat)]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6]
```

With a different starting value:

```
>>> i = 5
>>> [x for x in range(i, i+q) for y in range(repeat)]+[i+q for y in range(max_len%repeat)]
[5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11]
```